# События в операционных системах

Tags: события

Добрый вечер! У меня появился такой вопрос: представьте такую ситуацию. Предположим у вас открыта папка с помощью проводника Windows. В папке имеются файлы. Скажем, некая программа, работающая в фоне удаляет из этой папки файл. И это изменение тут же отображается в проводнике - удаленный файл исчезает в проводнике. Так вот вопрос: как это реализуется программно? На ум приходит только то, что при открытии проводника начинает работать некий таймер, с помощью которого достаточно часто (скажем 30 раз в секунду) происходит считывание файлов из папки и если эти файлы изменились (например были удалены) то окно проводника перерисовывается с учетом этих изменений. Но насколько я понимаю такое отслеживание очень расточительно - ведб нужно делать это очень часто, причем не для одного окна, а для множества прочих объектов. Есть ли у кого-то какие-либо идеи на этот счет?

Comment: Не знаю, как в Windows, а в Linux посмотрите `man inotify`. Думаю в винде есть аналогичный механизм оповещения о событиях.

Comment: в винде вроде даже ещё лучше этот момент сделан, можно подписаться сразу рекурсивно на события а не вешать на каждую вложенную директорию отдельный листенер. см описание к "Process Monitor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу linux уже написали. А в windows - читайте [статью](http://www.softcraft.ru/coding/winapi/watcher.shtml) с примерами кода и конечно же [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

у windows есть очереди событий направленные в оконное приложение откуда все и отлавливается, если надо перехватить некое событие стороннего приложения то устанавливается так называемый глобальный хук который из очереди windows отлавливает нужное событие (ну например команды клавишь направленые в explorer)